# Can't connect to local Node App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, safari, mean-stack

I just started with a little bit *MEAN*-Magic by following along [**this**](https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/) tutorial. It was working pretty good (installation and so on). Now I'm stuck at:

**STEP 4**: Creating an ExpressJS application

I executed `express mytestapp`, `cd mytestapp`, `npm install`and `node app.js`and am able to see the folder structure in the Terminal, but if I open Safari with "*http://localhost:3000*" I get the message

*Safari can't Connect To Server... Safari can't open the page "localhost:3000" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"*

How can I troubleshoot this? I'm totally new to this. (Not sure if this matters, but I'm working from a mac at the moment).

Comment: I assume you get the same problem if you try http://127.0.0.1:3000/ ?

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error.

Comment: And do you see "Express server listening on port 3000" when you start up? If you have an environment variable PORT set, then app.js may have started on another port.

Comment: When I wrote `node app.js` nothing showed up on the screen. Just the promt again.

Comment: I would guess that Mongo isn't running, did you do the mongod step and could you connect to Mongo?

Comment: I had one terminal open where I typed `mongod` and now I opened another one with `mongo test` (I hadn't that).

Comment: Now I see *[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52541 #2 (1 connection now open)* in the first terminal.

Comment: I assume you need to visit `localhost:52541` or `127.0.0.1:52541`

Comment: None of these two work. I think the *new connection* is coming from the `mongo test` I just typed. Not the `node app.js`, since the connection is brand new.

Comment: `ps -e|grep node` only returns the grep process. I don't even think node is running, but if I type `node app.js` the curser just jumps into the next line... What is happening here?

Comment: What does you app.js file actually contain? Can you post it?